# How to remove rows based on data from one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of people with columns for Email, Name, Gender etc.
I have another list of emails that I need them to be subtracted from the first list.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do it by writing vba code that iterates from the bottom up and if the email is found then delete the row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it through the user interface, without code.

You can add a helper column with a formula like this on Sheet1 (assuming A1 has the email and the other list is on Sheet2, with email in column A)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1),"remove","")
```

Copy down. Now you can sort by that column and delete all rows that have the word "remove" in the helper column. After that, you can delete the helper column.